# When compiling Apache IoTDB coding through mvn, why did the failed to execute project error popped out with return code of 1?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Please tell me, if I get an error when compiling the Apache IoTDB code using the mvn instruction, which part of the IoTDB coding should I check and how should I solve it? The error information was like `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.cmake-maven-project:cmake-maven-plugin:3.7.2-b1:compile (cmake-compile) on project client-cpp-tools-thrift: Return code: 1 - > [Help 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the compiled library of Apache IoTDB in Windows environment from: https://github.com/thulab/iotdb-daily-build/releases, and see if this compiled coding solve your problem.